# How can I design a UI for iOS with a diamond shaped drill down interface?

Tags: tables, ios, drilldown

I have a basic drill down interface for iOS devices.

A -> B -> C -> D

The problem is that the following interface would work equally well:

A -> C -> B -> D

What I need is some kind of diamond shaped UI.

A -> (B and C) -> D

How can I design a UI for iOS with a diamond shaped drill down interface?

P.S. Both B and C must have a selection made, it is not an B or C situation.

Comment: I would suggest that you pick one of them. Either B -> C or C -> B...

Comment: But Mr. Angeltveit that'd make the view controller stack too big. The situation is more like A -> B -> C -> D -> E. I just didn't want to complicate the question beyond the essential problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cover all the possible ways to get to an object, just select the one that makes the most sense and make it your navigation model. This is true for most cases in general, but it's especially important on mobile, where it's difficult to provide a complex navigation system.